# How to implement Logic like "Tip of the day" dynamically every day 24 Hrs in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table "Tips" which has several rows. At the home page I need to display a random single tip as "Tip of the day". After 24 hours dynamically I should display a random tip for another 24 hours. How to implement this concept?

look link below for reference which displays 4-5 quotes everyday. [sample - click here](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes_of_the_day.html)

Should I create a new table to have "tip of the day" where it is deleted and inserted a new row every day? Or to implement a Caching Technique on the server.

Guide me a best way to implement. The application is to be hosted on shared hosting plan , so there is no way to run windows service on the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can e.g. generate the SHA-1 hash of the current date and then compute its remainder on the modulo of the total tips count, which will get you the number of the "Tip of the day".

For example,

```
TipOfTheDay[] tips;

var now = DateTime.Now;
var buffer = new byte[] { (byte)(now.Year % 256), (byte)(now.Year / 256), (byte)now.Month, (byte)now.Day };
SHA1 encoder = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(); 
var hash = encoder.ComputeHash(data);
int tipNumber = 0;
for(var b in hash) {
    tipNumber += b;
    tipNumber %= tips.Count;
}
return tips[tipNumber];
```

This will return you a new (pseudo-random) tip every day, and the tip will remain the same during the day.

Comment: Thank you for guiding. Can you explain how it works and how to make work on asp.net? Tips is stored in the sql database. Will the above code triggers every 24 hours?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asp.Net MVC you can use output cache attribte and set the duration as 24 hr.

```
[OutputCache(Duration=86400)]
```

for asp.net, you can add `<%@ OutputCache duration="86400" varybyparam="None" %>` on the control view

Comment: I need to display every tip for all users. output cache stores value on client machine right?

Comment: By default it will be cached in both server and browser, you can set cache location to "Any","Client","Server","None","Downstream" or "ServerAndClient". [OutputCache(Location=System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server)]