# How to implement logic Tip of the day to your android app everytime it is launched?

Tags: android

I want to add logic tip of the day to my Android app. I searched the web but the information is only about the dialog box. Please help me with the code if possible.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Maybe you can try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426546/how-to-implement-logic-like-tip-of-the-day-dynamically-every-day-24-hrs-in-asp

Comment: Perhaps tip of the day is best implemented using a dialog box? Why does a dialog box not fit your needs?

Comment: Actually i want random tip to be generated everytym the app is launched.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `onCreate()` method in your activity. You should also check in the `onResume()`. Because when the app goes in background it isn't destroyed, thus it doesn't get recreated when launched again. Check the day then and put it in shared preferences. On the next start or resume, you will have to check if the day is different from the previous entry in Shared Preferences.

Reference: [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)
Reference: [Shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

In these two methods you can use a notification builder to let it pop up. Or use something else.

Reference: [Notification Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show daily tips one time per day (kotlin)

1. Get the actual day

```
        var currentDay = dateFormat!!.format(calendar!!.time).substring(0, 2)
        if (currentDay.startsWith("0")) {
            currentDay = currentDay[1].toString()
        }
```

This gets only date format like "1", "10","9"....

2. Check if the current day is not equal to the last day informed on sharedPreferences

```
        private val preferencesDailyTips = "DailyTips"
        lateinit var preference: SharedPreferences
        ...
        preference = getSharedPreferences("DailyTips", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        if (currentDay != preference.getString("DailyTips", "")) {
            val editor = preference.edit()
            editor.putString(preferencesDailyTips, currentDay)
            editor.apply()
            showDailyTip() // Your function...
        }
```